# <gfe:entry-ttl> and <gfe:entry-tti> elements are not allowed under <gfe:replicated-region>

Tags: geode, spring-data-gemfire

Im using Apache Geode `1.14.4` and spring-data-geode version `2.7.2`.

I have following Region config which fails to bring up my app.

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode/spring-geode.xsd">
    <gfe:replicated-region id="regionId" cache-ref="myCacheRef">
        <!-- When region.get(k) is a cache-miss, this loader will be called to load the value (eg. from db) -->
        <gfe:cache-loader ref="myLoader"/>
        <gfe:cache-writer ref="myWriter"/>
        <!-- Time-to-live (TTL) is used for creation and put operations -->
        <gfe:entry-ttl timeout="300" action="DESTROY"/>
        <!-- Idle timeout (TTI) is used for get and netSearch operations -->
        <gfe:entry-tti timeout="300" action="DESTROY"/>
    </gfe:replicated-region>
</beans>
```

The exact error is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 29 in XML document from file [C:\Users\sjoshi\context\geode-context.xml] is invalid; 
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 29; columnNumber: 56; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 
Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode":entry-ttl}'.
One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode":membership-attributes, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode":gateway-sender, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode":gateway-sender-ref, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode":async-event-queue, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode":async-event-queue-ref, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode":subscription, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode":eviction, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode":lookup-region, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode":replicated-region, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode":partitioned-region, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode":local-region, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode":client-region}' is expected.
```

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of entry elements is not right. According to [xsd](https://www.springframework.org/schema/geode/spring-geode.xsd) it should be as following:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
              xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode 
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/geode/spring-geode.xsd">

    <gfe:replicated-region id="regionId" cache-ref="myCacheRef">
        <gfe:entry-ttl timeout="300" action="DESTROY"/>
        <gfe:entry-tti timeout="300" action="DESTROY"/>
        <gfe:cache-loader ref="myLoader"/>
        <gfe:cache-writer ref="myWriter"/>
    </gfe:replicated-region>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I provided detailed information to the problem you are experiencing in ***Spring Data for Apache Geode*** (SDG) [Issue #616](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/issues/616), the ticket you filed.

See my responses [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/issues/616#issuecomment-1192955448), [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/issues/616#issuecomment-1192980536) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/issues/616#issuecomment-1192984627).